# The Caravan Problem

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, planar-graphs

I want to make a simulation for fun about a caravan moving goods.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a planar graph (towns and non-overlapping roads)

Let $N$ different tradeable goods exist (fish, iron, gold, $\ldots$)

Let each vertex (town) have a stockpile $\boldsymbol{S_i} \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ where $i$ is the index associated with the vertex ($i = 1, \ldots, |V|)$

The stockpile is the amount of goods stored at each vertex.

Let $\boldsymbol{D_i} \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ be a vector expressing how much a town "wants" a good. The value indicates a "target". If it's lower than the current stockpile then it should try to sell (get rid of good), if it's higher than it wants to buy (acquire this good).

Let the caravan be stationed at $v \in V$

The caravan starts with no goods and has infinite inventory space and has sufficient money to acquire any needed good. To move a good, the caravan first needs to purchase it at a town that has that good (ideally helping them reduce their target) and then moving on the graph and selling it to another town.

The caravan can see the entire graph, but can only move $M$ times.

1. How can the caravan move optimally to satisfy the demands of each town (minimize least squares of $S_i - D_i, \forall i \in 1, \ldots, N$? (I might want to change the exact details of the minimization function but assume OLS for now)) It is fine that caravan goes beyond a town's target to compensate for another town.
2. I'm assuming this algorithm would be slow, would it be possible to approximate it and make sure that the amount of tradeable goods doesn't change?

Comment: Why does the graph need to be planar?  Wouldn't Hamiltonian make more sense?

Comment: Simply because I want edges to represent roads to neighboring towns, without having overlapping roads. I'm not familiar with Hamiltonian graphs enough to see if this property is holding

Comment: What are the possible actions for the merchant ? Buy and sell goods ? Does he have infinite goods on him or does he need to buy them to dispatch them on other towns ? Can a town sell more than its target to compensate with another town ? (because with least squares, it is better to have two capacities half filled than one filled and the other empty). As stated, your problem is very unclear, would you mind detailing more ?

Comment: @caduk good questions. Perhaps thinking of the merchant as a caravan would make more sense. The merchant starts with no goods, assume he has enough money for any action and sufficient inventory space too. When the merchant enters a town he can purchase any amount of goods and sell any amount. Before selling goods in a town he would need to have bought them in a previous town. A town can sell more than it's target to compensate with others. So essentially the merchant is just moving goods around

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, can you edit your post with this information, so the question is self-contained?

Comment: @caduk I've added multiple clarifications to the problem statement, including changing merchant to "caravan" since the problem is more about moving goods around then the merchant trying to maximize profit (could have been a source of confusion)

Comment: Try a greedy algorithm. Buy from the town with the most surplus and sell to the town with the most deficit. This is similar to TSP so I think it is NP hard

Comment: Is there any relationship between $M$ and $|V|$?  Can a town be visited more than once?  Must the caravan return to $v$ at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Its like a TSP with an order (caravan needs to buy before moving to sell)
assuming $ S_{i,n},D_{i,n}$ are known parameters then
Define:
$ \tau_{i,n} = 1$ if town $i$ has $ S_i \gt D_i$(buy here) of good $n$,
$-1$ if $ S_i \lt D_i$(sell here), else 0
Let $ C_i$ be known cost of visiting a town $i$.
Variables
$ s_{i,n}=1$ if caravan sells good $n$ at town $i$
$ b_{i,n} = 1$ if good $n$ is purchased at town $i$
$ 0 \le V_{i} \le \vert V \vert $: is the order a town $i$ is visited. Can be 0 also if town is not visited at all.

Constraints you'd need
(1) $ \tau_{i,n} = b_{i,n}-s_{i,n}$
(2)  $ s_{i,n}+b_{i,n} \le 1 \quad \forall i \ \ \forall n$

(3)  $ \sum_{j: (i,j) \in E} b_{j,n} \le s_{i,n} \ \forall n$

(4)  $ V_i \le \sum_n s_{i,n}+b_{i,n} \le MV_i$
(5) $ s_{i,n} + b_{j,n}-1 \le M(V_i - V_j) \quad \forall j \neq i \quad \forall i$
Or
(6)  $ \sum_n\tau_{i,n}V_i \le \sum_n \tau_{j,n}\sum_j V_j \quad \forall j \neq i \quad \forall i$